# how to refer to the property of bean used in BeanEditForm (tapestry5) in Java?

Tags: java, selection, tapestry

I've got in my .tml file something like this:

```
<t:beaneditform t:id="adForm" object="editableAd"
                        reorder="actiontype,shops,movies,streams,widgets" ....
```

My question is how to access (refer) **actionType**, which is an Enum (and in fact SELECT) in .java file? I just need to handle event when user changes the value of this select (dropdown), obviously before submitting the form itself.

If something like this would work for me...

```
@OnEvent(component = "adForm.actionType", value=EventConstants.VALUE_CHANGED)
    public void actionTypeValueChanged(String value) {
      log.info("value is: " + value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To be updated with the changed value in a **Select** html component on the client side, have a tapestry select component in your template file with a `t:zone` attribute (i.e. in your case it could point to any dummy zone, this is only needed to be set correctly if you need to update a zone when a value is changed)

Also set the `t:value` attribute to your enum variable in your page\component java file, usually this variable will be annotated with tapestry's `@Property`.

Example:

```
<t:select t:id="myEnumVariable" t:zone="dummyZone" t:value="myEnumVariable"/>
```

`myEnumVariable` is used to refer to your class's variable AND to act as an ID (i.e. the actual string **myEnumVariable** is used as an id), this is not necessary, but it's more readable and maintainable that way)

```
public class MyClass{
    @Property
    private MyEnum myEnumVariable;

    @OnEvent(component = "myEnumVariable", value=EventConstants.VALUE_CHANGED)
    public void actionTypeValueChanged(**MyEnum** newValue) {
        this.myEnumVariable = newValue; // <<<<<<
        log.info("value is: " + myEnumVariable );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand the part with OnEvent and Property annotations, where handler is bound to the bean property. That's in the bean class, right? But I don't understand the creation of t:select in .tml file. The thing is that select is created automatically within a beaneditform, based on the enum type of actionType property. So, I don't explicitly define select there. If I run the app just with the Java code changes, nothing happens so far.

Comment: I was able to exclude automatically generated select from the beaneditform and add my own with t:value="actionType". This new select gives me an option to select from ActionType enum, so this is correct. But I don't get event, actionTypeValueChanged() is not called, cause I don't see the log.

Comment: @MartinC, In your first comment "That's in the bean class, right?", this should be in the class representing your tapestry component\page. The only tapestry related code I know that could be placed in a bean class is the `@NonVisual` (i.e. to stop `BeanEditors` from considering the annotated member) and `@Inject` (i.e. to specify a specific constructor for automatic instantiation). I don't know why wouldn't that work with a `BeanEditor` without throwing errors or at least warnings in the logs. Speaking of the logs, are you saying you don't have access to the logs or that nothing is logged ?

Comment: Hi, your solution works for me, but I had to define explicitly my own select. I still don't know how to handle change in automatically generated dropdown, which is in fact bean property.

Comment: Would you please include your template and java code in your question ?

Comment: Hi
sorry, I am bit out of time, I used your solution and in handlers, I just pass the value from select to the bean property and backwards and everything works. Thank you again. I've just given up about the initial solution.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your issue but, when possible, if you post your code, I'd be glad to help you complete your original approach.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I guess @user1557837 answer is something I will look into later on.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using the ChenilleKit framework for tapestry you could try using the
framework's [OnEvent mixin](http://chenillekit.codehaus.org/chenillekit-tapestry/ref/org/chenillekit/tapestry/core/mixins/OnEvent.html).

You 'll find the example on the link I share but basically you add two attributes the select tag:

```
<t:select t:id="myselect" ... t:mixins="ck/OnEvent" t:event="change" />
```

then you add the event handler on your java class:

```
@OnEvent(component="myselect", value='change')
public void onChangeDoSomething(String value) {
```

hope that helps, by the way I think Muhammad's answer is equally correct (and doesn't requires the use of an extra framework).

Comment: Hi, there is no select tag. There is only beaneditform, select is generated automatically by Tapestry from enum, so I don't have any markup for it. I could only exclude it and define my own select, but that's rather weird workaround...

Comment: Sorry, you should redefine (or override) the select property so you can add the t:zone parameter to the select tag, as in the Select api docs says, that's the only way the select component will fire the valuechanged event.

Comment: If you don't want to redefine the value the only left is to contribute to BeanBlockSource and defining a new way to render the enum in the beaneditform. In this new definition you could define the t:zone parameter perhaps using the (optional) t:zone paramter of the beaneditform component (where this select is nested) but I really don't know if you 'll have access to the value of the t:zone paramter (maybe if the beanedit form puts it in the Environment).

good luck

Comment: thank you for your valuable comments. I guess I will come back to this issue when refactoring the code, now, I use the workaround with exclude and add new select, so that works. Time pressure as usual :) But thank you again.